# Cannot auth to Firebase Storage even though I'm authenticated anonymously

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter, firebase-storage

I have anonymous auth working.

```
Flutter: signed in! FirebaseUser({displayName: null, providerId: Firebase, uid: 6vj0tYIQsUSjsdiJfkjid37NhKk2, providerData: [], isEmailVerified: false, email: null, photoUrl: null, isAnonymous: true})
```

[image]

And my rules are as follows

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And I keep getting this error

[image]

But if I change my rules to public

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

It works!

[image]

Any idea what's going on?

This is my code. I cannot find anywhere to feed it my auth information, and I'm not sure if I even have to.

```
final DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase().reference();
final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage().ref();
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<void> connect() async {
  this.app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'when-coin-test',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      googleAppID: '1:3739845793845:ios:9287349823487',
      apiKey: 'AoijojsoafhsdiohIOSHFOSHfoiShdfoijdf',
      databaseURL: 'https://when-coin-test.firebaseio.com',
      storageBucket: 'gs://when-coin-test.appspot.com'
    )
  );
  print("connected to firebase!");

  this.user = await this.auth.signInAnonymously();
  print("signed in! $user");

  await _getAllSocialImageUrls();
  print("got socialUrls! $socialUrls");

}
```

Comment: So many thoughts going through my head here: I am pretty sure that configure is totally optional and I know that you do not need to sign in more than once. I guess that your sign in is not processed by the time you made your request.

Comment: I do await the login, though. And they are logging sequentially with success.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot are you saying that configure is optional? do you have a snippet showing how to set up without configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the credentials you passed into `configure` are just not working.

The configuration of *Firebase for Flutter* is not documented everywhere. Following step **1.** for *Android* and step **2.** for *iOS* [right here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#setup), you are already set up with your credentials.
`FirebaseAuth` will work with that and automatically integrate with the other *Firebase plugins*, like Firebase Storage.

Because of this, you can actually **omit** all of this:

```
this.app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
  ...
);
```

You can still use [`FirebaseApp`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/lib/src/firebase_app.dart) if you would like to work with multiple projects, but for your use case, you do *not need* to access the class at all.

[`firebase_core`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_core)'s purpose as a package is describe on the page as follows:

> #### Firebase Core for Flutter
>
> A Flutter plugin to use the Firebase Core API, which enables connecting to ***multiple** Firebase apps*.

Comment: Does that mean I don't even need firebase_core at all? (one project per app)

Comment: @LukePighetti *Exactly*, each package handles that on its own and adds the required native code *automatically*. I added some *more information* to my answer. Maybe you could adjust your question to direct people that have a similar problem in a wider scope to this page.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for how to improve my question?

Comment: @LukePighetti The question itself is fine. It is just not very general. This problem does not only apply to Firebase Storage, but to all the Firebase plugins for Flutter. Just something I thought of.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious and so I went to initiate the FirebaseApp without the `.configure()` method (as [creativecreatorormaybenot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342520/6509751) mentioned).

Doing it this way, everything works fine.

```
app = FirebaseApp(name: 'when-coin-test');
user = await this.auth.signInAnonymously();
```

This example is out of date: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: I was able to propose my answer as well with some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app) instead of FirebaseAuth.instance. Or you can use my simple FirebaseWrapper.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


Future<void> main() async {

    await FirebaseWrapper.init();

    runApp(
        MyApp(),
    );
}

class FirebaseWrapper {

    static FirebaseAuth _auth;
    static Firestore _firestore;
    static FirebaseStorage _storage;


    static Future<void> init() async {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

        final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
            name: 'Overload',
            options: FirebaseOptions(
                googleAppID: Platform.isIOS ? '1:0000000000:ios:000000000000' : '1:fbfbfbfbfbfbfbbf:android:fbfbfbfbfbfbfbfbf',
                gcmSenderID: '14325256252',
                apiKey: 'JHasjkhvKJKhfgKfdlLDFLkDLkDJhD',
                projectID: 'some-project-id',
            ),
        );

        _auth = FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app);

        _firestore = Firestore(app: app);

        _storage = FirebaseStorage(
            app: app, storageBucket: 'gs://overload-57752.appspot.com');
    }

    static FirebaseAuth auth() {
        return _auth;
    }

    static Firestore firestore() {
        return _firestore;
    }

    static FirebaseStorage storage() {
        return _storage;
    }
}
```